# Which reputation number applies to the badge proccess?

Tags: support, badges

I was wondering if I can go sleep now. My card (when I hover over my name at the topbar) shows that I received 191 reputation today, however, my /reputation/ shows 201 (yes, I tried to press F5 on both pages).

```
            today   week    month
reputation  181     1126    191

** rep today: 201
```

I was wondering, which one of these numbers applies [Epic](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/145/epic) and other cap-based badges?

Comment: yes, you can go to sleep now.  it's only a game, it's not life. you can get up and play again tomorrow.

Comment: @tvanfosson: I need to cap rep 150 times!

Comment: been there, done that, got the t-shirt...and now it's just a old rag to clean up after the dog with.

Comment: @tvanfosson: I've got  229 anyway now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rep number shown at the top of the page is a denormalized number. It is not always accurate; it may or may not reflect certain changes to your rep such as deleted questions and answers. The correct rep value is the one shown at the bottom of your **/reputation** page.

As to the difference in rep for those two numbers you've shown, I can only guess that the bottom number is probably the accurate one, but you can check your **/reputation** page to see which number is correct.  The **/reputation** page is the gold standard; it shows the actual, true rep you've earned.

Automatic recalcs don't happen that often.  When they do, it will have the same effect as you pushing the recalc button on the **/reputation** page; it will reset all of the denormalized numbers to their correct values.  If you're looking to get a badge, I would hold off on recalcing until you've earned the badge.

Comment: Just a one small question. When I'd hit 199 rep, and after recount it would go up to 210, would that day count into consecutive days?

Comment: If it hasn't already been counted yet, then yes, it should be counted as a consecutive rep cap day. If you recalc, and your rep for the day goes to 210, it should count as a consecutive day at zulu midnight, 5 PM PST.